# Trying to install rails. Error1. no such file to load -- openssl Error 2. undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl

I'm trying to get rails downloaded to my machine. I am pretty sure this is an older setup and am not sure what is wrong. I've been at this for hours. Whenever I type `rails c` I get...

```
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

    $ sudo gem install rails

You can then rerun your "rails" command.
```

Then I type what it says to type and get:

```
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
        no such file to load -- openssl
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

I explored this for a while and thought I didn't have openssl installed so I downloaded it and now when i type `openssl` i get a prompt that looks like "OpenSSL>" and when I type `whereis openssl`, I get `usr/bin/openssl`. Those two things lead me to believe that openssl is installed on my laptop but for some reason when I go to `gem install rails` I still get an error.

My ruby version is 1.8.7. This is the version the application I'm trying to gain access to was built in. I'm on a MacOS Mojave 10.14.16. If anyone has any tips or could point me in the right direction I'd very much appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to install OpenSSL first and recompile ruby again:

RVM:

```
rvm pkg install openssl
rvm reinstall ruby-1.8.7 --with-gcc=gcc-4.7 --with-openssl-dir=$rvm_path/usr
```

please write complete name version of ruby-1.8.7

Comment: Thanks, the first line worked but the second line is gving me, "You requested building with 'gcc-4.7' but it is not in your path." I typed `whereis gcc` and got '/usr/bin/gcc'.

My current $PATH is = /Users/cadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/bin:/Users/cadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/bin:/Users/cadams/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/bin:/Users/cadams/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/bin/gcc:/usr/local/munki:/Users/cadams/.rbenv/shims

gcc -v is 'Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1'

Comment: @ARC can use second line without `--with-gcc flag` work also.

Comment: Ok, It's now gving me "command gem pristine  --version ' failed, you need to fix these gems manually." and "Error running '__rvm_with ruby-1.8.7-p374 gemset_pristine"

I'll try to look some of these up.

Comment: Run these commands in sequence in terminal, and close all and open new terminal
```rvm get stable
rvm autolibs enable
rvm reinstall all --force```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Today I am still working on this problem. I got a new error to show up saying `no such file to load -- zlib`. I also had to switch to rbenv because I believe I can no longer get rvm after doing `rvm implode` because their site is down. (I think it's a domain name renewal thing.) If you happen to have any tips for solving this and using rbenv im all ears! Thanks again!